# How to reuse validation rules for different endpoints using Express Validator?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I want to reuse Express Validator schemas in different endpoints, for instance in POST, and PUT requests, I don't want to create two different schemas (one for each endpoint), because if something changes in one schema it might have to change in the other. I used Express Validator in my last project and changing the validation rules in one schema required me to change them in the other.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can make a file and name it `validators.js`

```js
const { body } = require('express-validator');

const myReusebleValidator = [
    body('username').isEmail(),
    body('password').isLength({ min: 5 }),
]
module.exports.myReusebleValidator = myReusebleValidator
```

And then in the routes put them just before `controller`

routes.js

```js
const { myReusebleValidator } = './validators'
const dumyControllerPost = (req ,res) => {
 res.send("Hello")
}
const dumyControllerPut = (req ,res) => {
 res.send("World")
}

app.put('/put' , myReusebleValidator ,  dumyControllerPut)
app.post('/post' , myReusebleValidator ,  dumyControllerPost)
```